# Basic I know, but how to I extrude and align these surfaces to a face or edge?

Tags: faces, extrude, snapping

I've tried doing a search but can't find anything outside of basic extruding press <kbd>E</kbd>. Not sure what terms to use.

I'm trying to modify an existing model I have and finally got a block in here, but can't figure out how to extrude it to line up perfectly on these edges. It's my workaround cause I couldn't figure out how to turn this half triangle square into a square.

I'm used to SketchUp where I can extrude and it auto aligns to edges.

[image]

Responding to @moonboots

[image]

Ok I tried the snapping and none of the options do what I want. It's snapping to other things it touches. Here's a video (animated gif) of what I do in SketchUp. I'm trying to do the same thing. It's super simple in sketchup and I'm assuming it's super easy in Blender, but don't know how.

[image]

Comment: hello, what is the final shape that you are trying to achieve? Could you make a drawing?

Comment: Added a new image to answer your question. I had somehow messed these squares and deleted some verticies and trying to re-build these back.

Comment: Easiest to delete it all except the bottom face, select that, and Extrude it up on the Z axis using the Snap to Vertex option to snap the height to the next one along. You can always add the edges to make the faces triangular afterwards if you need them.

Comment: "using the Snap to Vertex option to snap the height to the next one along" how do I do that part? @JohnEason

Comment: [Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#snapping) is the Blender manual section on snapping and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c0Evpf8V3A) is a tutorial from Ryan King on using Blender's Snapping tool.

Comment: Ok I tried that @JohnEason watched the video but doesn't do or show what I'm trying to do. I added an Animated Gif to the question on what I do in sketchup.

Comment: Ok. It does take a bit of practice and it looks as if it actually works the same way in sketchup. Without actually enabling snapping by clicking the horseshoe icon, set Vertex on the snapping dropdown (four dots) then with the face selected hit E > Z, hold down CTRL and move the cursor over the top corner of the other object until the cursor changes then hit Enter. I'll try and rustle up an animated Gif tomorrow but it's nearly 1am here...

Comment: Not had time to do a demo, but just as slight modification: With your face selected, hover over the reference corner then hit Z. Hold down Ctrl whcih should extrude the face to the same height as the reference then press Enter. Job done.

Comment: Omg! I knew it would be so easy once I knew!!! That's it. Thank you! Make this comment an answer so I can give it credit. That's exactly what I was trying to do! @JohnEason Thank you so much.

Comment: Quick Question, @JohnEason  When I extrude into something like going down from an existing level it just moves the lines down but the faces still say in place, there a way to properly extrude into something so faces and all move?

Comment: I think we'll need to see a Blend file for that one, preferably asked in another question as this thread is getting too long.

Comment: @JohnEason submit your comment as an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a <kbd>Plane</kbd> and a reference <kbd>Cube</kbd> as an example.
Go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> and <kbd>Face</kbd> selection mode, set the <kbd>Snapping</kbd> mode to <kbd>Vertex</kbd> on the dropdown.

[image]

Then hover the cursor over the corner of the reference cube, Hit <kbd>E</kbd> then hold down the <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> key. That will extrude the face up to the same height as the cube.

[image]

Hit <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to complete the operation.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is perfect!